# how to render disabled button by if statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to disable a button in a react component when a state of checkedIds is empty, the code to disable button is just like this:

```
<Button disabled> disabled </Button>
```

But when I try this it don't work

```
<Button {if(this.state.checkedIds.length===0) {
    return disabled;
  }}>
      Delete Selected 
  </Button>
```

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If-else doesn't directly work like that, you should make use of ternary operator and return a boolean value like

```
<Button disabled={(this.state.checkedIds.length == 0? true: false)}>
      Delete Selected 
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
<Button disabled={this.state.checkedIds.length===0} >
  Delete Selected 
</Button>
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: @iamnewbie Are you sure its a native button component? Check out this pen I made to illustrate this. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqdpJZ?editors=0010

Comment: The only difference that I can see is that you have done strict checking which I don't think mattered much here. your answer should also have worked for him. Still can't understand with these details why it didn't work